# Change Default MySQL or PostgreSQL Port Number While Starting Default SQL Proxy Connections

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I need to connect several Postgres & MySQL Cloud SQL service from my ETL server. I am using SQL proxy to connect with this database services.

But problem is google doesn't allow default port for both MySQL and PostgreSQL, I can only connect with one instances at a time.

How I can change port number while creating SQL proxy connections ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define different port numbers for different instances, like that:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:us-central1:myInstance=tcp:3306,myProject:us-central1:myInstance2=tcp:3307
```

This example is from GCP documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#multiple-instances